# A few questions about how UITableView reuses cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

All of the questions below are based on using this method:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomUserTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomUserTableViewCell
    cell.user_id = items[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

1. Is it valid to say that UITableView will cap the number of **instances** a UITableViewCell is created?
2. When a cell instance is "reused", do all its instance variables reset automatically? If not, should I write a method, `resetCell()`, that resets instance variables and then call it inside the `willDisplayCell` delegate?
3. I want my cell to update every time it receives a notification center post.  Where in my cell should I add observers to its notification center? I'm guessing I should call `listenToNotifications()` inside `willDisplayCell`.
4. Similarly, should I remove all the cell's notification observers every time `didEndDisplayingCell()` is called?
5. If I put all the reset/cleanup code inside `willDisplayCell` and `didEndDisplayingCell`, then what should I be putting inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

I wrote all my code assuming that each cell is its own instance (I didn't understand the concept of "reusing" cells), but now I know I can't think like that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Table view will create an instance of each type of cell that you have registered. From there, it'll create however many instances it requires to fully display itself on the screen. If the screen can fit 10 cells there will be 10 cells that will be reusable.
2. Reuse is an issue that is very common while using table/collectionViews. Table/CollectionViewCells have a method call `prepareForReuse` that is specifically meant for what you're indicating. One way to help prevent reuse issues is to have the owning controller be the one that manages your data. Every time `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called you should pass in the appropriate model object, which the cell will then take and configure itself with.

   ```
   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomUserTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomUserTableViewCell
       cell.configureWithObject(items[indexPath.row])
       return cell
   }

   class CustomUserTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

       override func prepareForReuse() {
           // set appropriate properties to nil that would incorrectly affect future cells
       }

       func configureWithObject(object: CustomModelObject) {
           // configure self with the passed in object
       }

   }
   ```
3. Chances are that you do not want your cells to observe a notification. That can result in very messy reuse problems. The best route to take would have your controller class pick up the notification and reload a specific cell at index path. (If you want me to elaborate on this I can)
4. I would recommend not doing it like I said in number 3, but if you do, have it inside the `deinit` on the cell. Make a call like `NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter().removeObserver(self)`
5. You should be putting reset/cleanup code anywhere. Cell for row will be the place that you pass your model object to the cell. The model object will essentially just contain data that needs to be displayed on the screen. Nothing complex that needs further processing(networking, parsing, database fetching, etc). Once the cell receives the object it should be a matter of setting view based properties with the data passed in.

Here's an example of data flow:

**View Model** - Contains logic for network calls and retrieving objects from the data base. If you do not have a data base, this could be used for setting up whatever representation you'll utilize as your data source.

**View Controller** - Holds onto the table view, which is automatically handling the reuse of all cells that you have registered. You conform to UITableViewDataSource, which is what gives you an opportunity to configure the cells. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you should be in a position where you can pass the cell a model object.

It is common to see calls like this:

```
let object = dataSource.objectForIndexPath(indexPath)
cell.configureWithObject(object)
```

**Cell** - Takes in a model object and configures itself with that data. A basic model object would contain a String property called title with the value "My Awesome Title!". When your cell gets the object all it will need to do is `titleLabel.text = modelObject.title`. It is ok do some additional, basic computation within cells, but the majority should be handled beforehand. It's a core principle to iOS design patterns: MVC, MVVM, etc. Labels generally don't have too many reuse issues, especially if you organize things like this, but images on the other hand do. In `prepareForReuse` it's common to have a call like `myImageView.image = nil`. That will ensure it is ready for the next time the cell gets configured.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan - this is very helpful and answered many of my questions.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 3):

1. yes, the number of instances will be managed for you.
2. No, they don't automatically reset. You can override `prepareForReuse` in your UITableViewCell subclass or you could handle all cases in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.
3. Assuming you want all of your cells to listen for the same notifications, you can register of notifications in `awakeFromNib` if you've used storyboards or an xib or you can register in your UITableViewCell subclass's init. Otherwise, you can do it `cellForRowAtIndexPath`
4. You should remove observing in `deinit`. You should also remove observing in `prepareForReuse`, if cells need to listen for different notifications.
5. `willDisplayCell` is generally used for static table views. You should setup your cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: Thanks. What if I want each cell to observe a different resource?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can just add observing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and remove in `prepareForReuse` but you should also remove in `deinit`